# Play audio when user exits my website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if there's a way to play audio when user exit my website?

for example. "thanks for visiting etc."

Comment: A surprise 'thank you' audio clip? I...would advise against it, personally. But yes, it's possible (*sort of*...). But don't. Please.

Comment: oh God, why? Please don't.

Comment: Are you working at Google TM.? is it a new feature coming up soon? :)

Comment: And visitor will never come back on your site again.

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't reliably play audio when the user leaves the website. Although you can *start* it (using `onbeforeunload`), it won't finish playing.

And seriously, if you did, it would only irritate people. :-)

Comment: Is this really possible to start and continue  playing until confirm dialog disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little test(still novice to the whole HTML5) and came up with this solution:

```
 <script>
         function myLoadHandler(evt)
        {
           var audio_file1 = document.getElementById('audioID');
            audio_file1.volume = 0
            audio_file1.play();
        }


        if ("onpagehide" in window) {
            window.addEventListener("pageshow", myLoadHandler, false);

        } else {
            window.addEventListener("load", myLoadHandler, false);
        }

    </script>

    <script>

        function playAudio() {
            var audio_file1 = document.getElementById('audioID');
            audio_file1.volume = 1
            audio_file1.play();
        }
    </script>

    <body onunload="playAudio()">
        <div>

            <div>
                <audio id="audioID" src="your_audio.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
            </div>


        </div>
    </body>
```

I tested it on latest Chrome and Firefox. Works only in Firefox-I guess that Chrome deletes all resources from memory quicker, than the javascript can execute.

Another weird thing is that even with preload="auto", the audio seems to actually buffer after it is played(either from script or from UI), so that's why I play it on load with volume 0.

And one more thing- like someone mentioned in the previous answer-it would probably be annoying. Use with caution.